# How to fix CMD get stuck after running python code

Tags: python, windows, command-prompt

So... as the title said, i have a python script which basically is yolo and finding license plate from given image. and it do it right! perfectly! but the issue is, recently when i call it, as usual, from cmd by typing 'python yolo.py' it will run and do the job i want but its stucks! and i can't type any other command at all. i have to close the cmd and run it again. the problem is this script suppose to call with another script which is a GUI, and when yolo run i cant use the program any more and should close it.
and i figure out that this script, without any change will run perfect on other computers.
is there anybody know how can i fix it?

```
import numpy as np
import time
import cv2


INPUT_FILE= ('Outputs/original.jpg')
OUTPUT_FILE=('Outputs/_yolo.jpg')
LABELS_FILE='data/classes.names'
CONFIG_FILE='data/yolov3.cfg'
WEIGHTS_FILE='data/lapi.weights'
CONFIDENCE_THRESHOLD=0.3

LABELS = open(LABELS_FILE).read().strip().split("\n")

np.random.seed(4)
COLORS = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(len(LABELS), 3),
    dtype="uint8")


net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet(CONFIG_FILE, WEIGHTS_FILE)

image = cv2.imread(INPUT_FILE)
(H, W) = image.shape[:2]

# determine only the *output* layer names that we need from YOLO
ln = net.getLayerNames()
ln = [ln[i[0] - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]


blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(image, 1 / 255.0, (416, 416),
    swapRB=True, crop=False)
net.setInput(blob)
start = time.time()
layerOutputs = net.forward(ln)
end = time.time()


print("[INFO] YOLO took {:.6f} seconds".format(end - start))


# initialize our lists of detected bounding boxes, confidences, and
# class IDs, respectively
boxes = []
confidences = []
classIDs = []

# loop over each of the layer outputs
for output in layerOutputs:
    # loop over each of the detections
    for detection in output:
        # extract the class ID and confidence (i.e., probability) of
        # the current object detection
        scores = detection[5:]
        classID = np.argmax(scores)
        confidence = scores[classID]

        # filter out weak predictions by ensuring the detected
        # probability is greater than the minimum probability
        if confidence > CONFIDENCE_THRESHOLD:
            # scale the bounding box coordinates back relative to the
            # size of the image, keeping in mind that YOLO actually
            # returns the center (x, y)-coordinates of the bounding
            # box followed by the boxes' width and height
            box = detection[0:4] * np.array([W, H, W, H])
            (centerX, centerY, width, height) = box.astype("int")

            # use the center (x, y)-coordinates to derive the top and
            # and left corner of the bounding box
            x = int(centerX - (width / 2))
            y = int(centerY - (height / 2))

            # update our list of bounding box coordinates, confidences,
            # and class IDs
            boxes.append([x, y, int(width), int(height)])
            confidences.append(float(confidence))
            classIDs.append(classID)

# apply non-maxima suppression to suppress weak, overlapping bounding
# boxes
idxs = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, CONFIDENCE_THRESHOLD,
    CONFIDENCE_THRESHOLD)

# ensure at least one detection exists
if len(idxs) > 0:
    # loop over the indexes we are keeping
    for i in idxs.flatten():
        # extract the bounding box coordinates
        (x, y) = (boxes[i][0], boxes[i][1])
        (w, h) = (boxes[i][2], boxes[i][3])

        color = [int(c) for c in COLORS[classIDs[i]]]

        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), color, 20)
        text = "{}: {:.4f}".format(LABELS[classIDs[i]], confidences[i])
        cv2.putText(image, text, (x, y - 5), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
            0.5, color, 20)
# save the output image
ratio = 490.0 / image.shape[1]
dim = (490, int(image.shape[0] * ratio))
resized_img = cv2.resize(image, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
cv2.imwrite(('Outputs/_yolo.jpg'), resized_img)

cropped_img = cv2.imread('Outputs/original.jpg')
cropped_img = cropped_img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
ratio = 490.0 / cropped_img.shape[1]
dim = (490, int(cropped_img.shape[0] * ratio))
resized_img = cv2.resize(cropped_img, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
cv2.imwrite(('Outputs/license.jpg'), resized_img)
```

CMD looks like this after script ends

[image: 1]

Update: i add threading.enumerate() at the end of the original script and the output was this

[image: 2]

Comment: Yes, i did it before and everything goes fine. as you can see the script will write two image at the end, at first execute it write them, but because its stuck in cmd, it cant execute twice and more. if i add print or anything else at the end, there will be execute fine as well but it will stuck after them again. basically it stuck at the bottom end of the script after every single lines of code executed.

Comment: tripleee, sorry english is not my first language '-_-

Comment: Did you try to figure out where the program gets stuck? Please be aware that relying on `print` statements may not be accurate, because of issues with flushing the stdout buffer.

Comment: not sure which python version you're running but you can try `threading.enumerate()` to see if there are no stuck/busy threads.

Comment: Karl Knechtel, thanks for your comment. yes i did, at first execute it will run every single line the script have and gets stuck after them. all 107 lines of code will run and then gets stuck, if i add more lines, they will run too and again gets stuck after them

Comment: Gerhard, thanks for your comment. im running python 3.7.0. can you guide me more? were should i put threading.enumerate() ?

Comment: have a look at this [link](https://www.bogotobogo.com/python/Multithread/python_multithreading_Enumerating_Active_threads.php#:~:text=the%20main%20process.-,threading.,have%20not%20yet%20been%20started.)

Comment: So, if you put explicit `exit()` at the end of the python script?

Comment: Nothing changed! is that possible that its more OS based problem?? Im using Windows10 2004 and write the code with standard windows 10 Code Writer, and notice that i didnt have problem with it, till yesterday